# Printing message when speech recognition result is not expected

Tags: python, python-3.4, voice-recognition

I use voice recognition and check a list for a colour, if what I said isn't in the list then it displays 'Colour not found' if it is found it displays 'Colour Found' I only want it to display each message once. 
The problem I am having is how to get the 'Colour not found' msg to display correctly.

```
# speech recognition

import speech_recognition as speech

#a lot of variables used for loops and conditions
voice = speech.Recognizer()
condition = False
condition2 = False
condition3 = False
boolean = False
counter = 0
counter2 = 0

while condition == False:
#with microphone input as the input
with speech.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")

    #variable = the input from the microphone
    audio = voice.listen(source)
    voiceRecog = voice.recognize_google(audio)
    try:
        #print the word that was heard
        print("\nYou said: " + voiceRecog)
    except speech.UnknownValueError:


        #if couldnt recognise then print this msg
        print("Sorry, we couldn't make that out. Try again!")

    except speech.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))


    #list of colours  for comparing   
    colours = ["blue", "red", "Green", "Orange", "yellow", "pink", "purple", "black"]

    #loop to check the word spoken against each word in the list
    for i in range(len(colours)):



        #so that if colour found it doesnt claim colour not found
        if boolean == False:
            condition2 = False

        #increase counters by 1 and change booleans to True
        #if spoken word matches any words in the list then output
        if colours[i] == voiceRecog:

            boolean = True
            condition2 = True
            condition3 = True
            counter += 1
            counter2 += 1

            print("\nColour Found!\n")

        #if user says "quit" then all booleans = True (exit all loops)
        elif voiceRecog == "quit":

            boolean = True
            condition = True
            condition2 = True
            condition3 = True

        #if none of other conditions check value of i and of con2
        else:
            #if end of list is reached and con2 = False then con3 = False
            if (i + 1) == len(colours) and condition2 == False:
                condition3 = False
                print(end = "")
    #if con3 = False then counter increase and print 'colour not found'
    if condition3 == False:            
        print("\nColour not found!\n\n")
        counter += 1

#once loop exited by saying quit, print attempts and successful attempts
print("\nYou checked for", counter, "colours and had", counter2, "successful attempts")
```

Above is my code and below is one scenario.

> > > Say something!
> > >
> > > You said: blue
> > >
> > > Colour Found!
> > >
> > > Say something!
> > >
> > > You said: Green
> > >
> > > Colour Found!
> > >
> > > Say something!
> > >
> > > You said: Dave Dave
> > >
> > > Say something!
> > >
> > > You said: quit
> > >
> > > You checked for 2 colours and had 2 successful attempts

There should be 3 attempts, but 2 successful attempts.

But if i do it the other way around:

> > > Say something!
> > >
> > > You said: Dave Dave
> > >
> > > Colour not found!
> > >
> > > Say something!
> > >
> > > You said: Steve Steve
> > >
> > > Colour not found!
> > >
> > > Say something!
> > >
> > > You said: red
> > >
> > > Colour Found!
> > >
> > > Say something!
> > >
> > > You said: black
> > >
> > > Colour Found!
> > >
> > > Say something!
> > >
> > > You said: quit
> > >
> > > You checked for 4 colours and had 2 successful attempts

I know the reason it is doing this, but i cannot figure out a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

```
# speech recognition

import speech_recognition as speech

#a lot of variables used for loops and conditions
voice = speech.Recognizer()
# Maintain status of each attempt. You can just use two variables successful_attempts and total_attempts also but status list might help you in maintaining more things like a list of tuples (color, result) etc
status = []
# successful_attempts, total_attempts = 0, 0

while True:
    #with microphone input as the input
    with speech.Microphone() as source:
        print("Say something!")

        #variable = the input from the microphone
        audio = voice.listen(source)
        voiceRecog = voice.recognize_google(audio)
        try:
            #print the word that was heard
            print("\nYou said: " + voiceRecog)
        except speech.UnknownValueError:


            #if couldnt recognise then print this msg
            print("Sorry, we couldn't make that out. Try again!")

        except speech.RequestError as e:
            print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))


        #list of colours  for comparing   
        colours = ["blue", "red", "Green", "Orange", "yellow", "pink", "purple", "black"]

        if "quit" in voiceRecog:
            break
        elif voiceRecog in colours:
            status.append(1)
            # successful_attempts += 1
            print("\nColour Found!\n")
        else:
            status.append(0)
            print("\nColour not found!\n\n")

        # total_attempts += 1

#once loop exited by saying quit, print attempts and successful attempts
print("\nYou checked for", len(status), "colours and had", sum(status), "successful attempts")
#print("\nYou checked for", total_attempts, "colours and had", successful_attempts, "successful attempts")
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i am a c# programmer i dont know about python syntaxes..here is my idea in c# try this it works `

```
    variable succes_Counter
variable unsuccess_Counter = 0
boolean color_not found = true
for i in range(len(colours)):
    {

            if colours[i] == voiceRecog
            {
                print("color found + colours[i] + ")
                succes_Counter += 1

                //HERE IT EXISTS FROM THIS LOOP

                break
            }
            elseif voiceRecog == "quit"

            //HERE IT EXISTS FROM THIS LOOP
                break


            else
                if color_not found == true
                {
                print(" color not found")

                unsuccess_Counter +=1

                color_not found = false
                }
        }


            color_not found = true
            print("\nYou checked for", unsuccess_Counter, "colours and had", succes_Counter, "successful attempts")
```